# require not defined with gulp-browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify

I'm trying to load modules in browser but I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

What I'm doing is creating the js in main.js and sending it over into the build as app.js

Here's my **gulpfile.js**

```
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
...
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    gulp.src('src/scripts/main.js')
        .pipe(browserify({
          insertGlobals : true,
          debug : !gulp.env.production
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'))
});
...
gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'concat', 'uglify', 'scripts']);
```

And my **main.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');
function getIt() {
var items = fs.readFileSync("../../data/data.json");
    var jsonItems = JSON.parse(items);
    console.log(jsonItems);
}
getIt();
```

How can I make this work in my template?

Comment: The error being thrown is when you run the gulp task or on the produced browserified code?

Comment: gulp seems to serve fine. Its just when i check the console in my index.html file. @MinusFour

Comment: I think there's no `fs` shim for the browser, but I can't say if that's the error. Honestly, I don't think there's an API that would let you retrieve a file by path.

Comment: @MinusFour if i require anything it doesn't work.

Comment: You mean, you are trying to call `require` from outside the produced script by browserify right?

Comment: @MinusFour hmm yes. I get that node is a backend scripting language, but then how to do I get my scripts to serve within the template?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101545/discussion-between-modelesq-and-minusfour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need external requires, you'll have to set the `require` property with the name of the file on the options object you pass to `browserify`. This will make `browserify` create the require function for you, so you can use later on use it outside the produced script.

```
 ...
 .pipe(browserify({
      insertGlobals : true,
      require : ['src/scripts/main.js'],
      debug : !gulp.env.production
    }))
  ...
```

Comment: Works... Well it still throws errors, but that might be on my end. Its progress!

Comment: Error: unhandled 'error' event Error: cannot find module 'src/scripts/main.js' from 'C:\Users\MyName\Projectname\src\scripts'

Comment: When is this error produced? When you browserify your code or when you run it on the browser?

Comment: this time its in the command line. preventing me from running the server

Comment: Most likely a path error then, try it with `main.js` instead of `src/scripts/main.js`.

Comment: Server launches, but throws 404 for main.js in browser.

Comment: Acutally my fault. : Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: This works. It was just an error within the gulpfile.js on my end. Thanks again!

Comment: Is there a way to get Browserify to bundle everything up in a single file rather than creating a client-side require?